# Node js : change csv file encoding programatically and parse to json

Tags: json, node.js, csv, encoding

I have a csv file with `utf-16` encoding, and need to change its enconding to `utf8` and convert it to JSON. I'm using `csvtojson` and `iconv-lite` modules. Here is my code:

```
var data = fs.createReadStream("myfile.csv");
data.pipe(iconv.decodeStream('utf16'))
  .pipe(iconv.encodeStream('utf8'))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("encoded.csv"));
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var csvStr = fs.readFileSync("encoded.csv").toString();
var converter = new Converter({});
converter.fromString(csvStr, function(err, jsonObj) {
    if (err) {
        handleError(err)
    }
    console.log(jsonObj)
});
```

The problem is that `iconv` converts the csv file with the right encoding, but when I read this file and call `toString()` method, it returns an empty string. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think asynchronous `pipe` might have something to do with it.  You can ensure you only open `encoded.csv` after it is completed by putting logic in the `end` event.

```
var data = fs.createReadStream("myfile.csv");
data.pipe(iconv.decodeStream('utf16'))
  .pipe(iconv.encodeStream('utf8'))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("encoded.csv"));

data.on('end', function() {

  var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
  var csvStr = fs.readFileSync("encoded.csv").toString();
  var converter = new Converter({});
  converter.fromString(csvStr, function(err, jsonObj) {
    if (err) {
        handleError(err)
    }
    console.log(jsonObj)
  });
}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options